# git local branches does not 'merges with the right remote branches'

Tags: git

I create 2 local branches to track remote branches:

```
# git branch1 -t origin/branch1
# git branch2 -t origin/branch2
```

But after I do a 'repo sync' and I do a `git remote show origin`, I see my branches are 'merges with remote dev, not branch1 and branch2' and they are 'pushes to' correctly' but it said 'local out of date'.

```
  # git remote show origin
  ...
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    branch1 merges with remote dev
    branch2     merges with remote dev
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    branch1 pushes to branch1 (local out of date)
    branch2     pushes to branch2     (local out of date)
```

how can I get my branches (branch1, branch2) to 'merges with the right branches'? 
And get my 'local no longer 'out of date'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the important thing to note is that you are typing `git branch` regardless of what your branch is named. `git branch1` is never a correct command.

You want this:

```
git branch -t origin/branch1
```

Alternately, you can do this if you want to check the branch out immediately:

```
git checkout -t origin/branch1
```

Also, if you already have a local branch, and want to set it to track a remote branch (rather than checking it out as new from the remote branch), you can do this:

```
git branch -u upstream/branch1 localbranch1
```

Please note that this syntax has recently changed and some of these commands will only work with Git 1.8.0+.

Answer (score 0):

The `branch1 merges with remote dev` message does not indicate that your branch *is* a merge with `origin/dev`, but that `origin/dev` is the default branch that *will be merged* into `branch1` if you run `git pull` without specifying a branch when you are currently on the `branch1` merge.